# checking starting and ending index of NA in dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a Dataframe with column name `sorted_no` as shown below

```
x_n$sorted_no
1  2 NA  3  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA NA  6 NA NA NA NA NA  7
```

I want the starting and ending index of `NA` values in this column like below

```
start end
  2    4
  5   13
 13   18
 18   24
```

Comment: if we start with `NA` is it ok to have `start` equal to `0` ? and if it ends with `NA` to have `end` equal to `length(x_n$sorted_no) + 1`

Answer (score 4):

In base `R`:

```
vec <- scan(text="1  2 NA  3  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA NA  6 NA NA NA NA NA  7", what=numeric())

diff_vec <- diff(is.na(c(0,vec)))
# [1]  0  0  1 -1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  1  0  0  0
# [18] -1  1  0  0  0  0 -1

data.frame(start= which(diff_vec==1)-1,
           end= which(diff_vec==-1))

#   start end
# 1     2   4
# 2     5  13
# 3    13  18
# 4    18  24
```

The `0` in `c(0,vec)` helps us be sure that we don't start with `NA`

---

Another solution with `data.table::rleid` and `tapply` :

```
library(data.table)
do.call(rbind,
        tapply(seq_along(vec)[is.na(vec)],rleid(vec)[is.na(vec)],
               function(x) data.frame(start=min(x)-1,end=max(x)+1)))

#    start end
# 3      2   4
# 6      5  13
# 8     13  18
# 10    18  24
```

Here I use `rleid` to create groups, and `seq_along` to create indices, and among these groups I take the `min` and `max` index.

---

A base solution using `rle`:

```
vec[is.na(vec)] <- Inf
rle_    <- rle(vec)
cumsum_ <- cumsum(rle_$lengths)
infs_   <- which(rle_$value == Inf)
data.frame(start = c(0,cumsum_)[infs_], end = cumsum_[infs_]+1)

#   start end
# 1     2   4
# 2     5  13
# 3    13  18
# 4    18  24
```

`base::rle` gives special treatment to `NAs` while `data.table::rleid` doesn't, so I used `Inf`, makes it somewhat less robust.

Comment: hey thanks for the help... Earlier I used diff function to finding the start and end of peak and valley in time series in this case I was stuck....

Answer (score 0):

data.table solution:

data:

```
x<-scan(text="1  2 NA  3  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA NA  6 NA NA NA NA NA  7", what=numeric())
```

code:

```
data.table(x,rleid(is.na(x)),seq_along(x))[is.na(x),.(start=V3[1]-1,end=V3[1]+.N),by=V2][,-1]

#   start end
#1:     2   4
#2:     5  13
#3:    13  18
#4:    18  24
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R solution:

```
which_na <- which(is.na(x_n$sorted_no))
which_notna <- which(!is.na(x_n$sorted_no))
data.frame(
  start = intersect(which_na - 1L, which_notna),
  end = intersect(which_na + 1L, which_notna)
)
  start end
1     2   4
2     5  13
3    13  18
4    18  24
```

One more, playing around with rle() (inspired by Mudskipper):

```
r <- rle(is.na(x_n$sorted_no))
data.frame(
  start = cumsum(r$lengths)[r$values] + 1,
  end = head(cumsum(r$lengths)[!r$values], sum(r$values))
)
```